# how to create new gridview and populate at code behind and send as email body?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to create new `gridview/datalist` and populate at code behind and send as `email body`?
I already have a `DataList`populated with item but I don't want to send all the columns in it. So, I want to generate a gridview with my desired columns for sending in email.
Below is what I have done so for

```
            GridView gv = new GridView();
            DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
            tbl.Columns.Add("Items", typeof(string));
            tbl.Columns.Add("Price", typeof(string));
            tbl.Columns.Add("Total", typeof(string));
            List<HiredList> hl = new List<HiredList>();
            hl = (List<HiredList>)Session["Hired"];
            foreach (var i in hl)
            {
                DataRow itms = tbl.NewRow();
                itms["Items"] = i.pName;
                itms["Price"] = i.price;
                itms["Total"] = i.pTotal;
            }
            //use AutoGenerateColumnsto let grid generate the column itself'
            gv.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            gv.DataSource = tbl;
            gv.DataBind();
```

Then send this gridview to

```
private string GetGridviewData(GridView gvList)
    {
        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        StringWriter strWriter = new StringWriter(strBuilder);
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(strWriter);
        gvList.RenderControl(htw);
        return strBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

But in return i get only , in the email I received.
I don't know where I made the mistake.

Comment: Did you tried anything so far? Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Answer (score 0):

**Sending data in gridview as a mail:**

```
 public void SendHTMLMail()
{
MailMessage Msg = new MailMessage();
MailAddress fromMail = new MailAddress("administrator@aspdotnet-suresh.com");
// Sender e-mail address.
Msg.From = fromMail;
// Recipient e-mail address.
Msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("suresh@gmail.com"));
// Subject of e-mail
Msg.Subject = "Send Gridivew in EMail";
Msg.Body += "Please check below data <br/><br/>";
Msg.Body += GetGridviewData(gvUserInfo);
Msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
string sSmtpServer = "";
sSmtpServer = "10.2.160.101";
SmtpClient a = new SmtpClient();
a.Host = sSmtpServer;
a.EnableSsl = true;
a.Send(Msg);
}
```

// This Method is used to render gridview control

```
public string GetGridviewData(GridView gv)
{
StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter strWriter = new StringWriter(strBuilder);
HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(strWriter);
gv.RenderControl(htw);
return strBuilder.ToString();
}
```

**Refer Link:**

http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/09/how-to-send-gridview-in-email-body-in.html

**For Plain HTML Page As Mail:**

http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/09/how-to-send-html-page-as-email-body-in.html

**For DataLists:**

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/269410-send-datalist-value-within-contact-page/

Hope its helpful.

Comment: Can I send DataList instead?